# Problema con $(document).on("ready"

Tags: jquery

Estoy intentando realizar una función cuando se termine de cargar con el oncanplay pero al momento de ponerle un document.ready me sale ReferenceError: loaderVideo is not defined

**HTML**

```html
<video src="https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/devstories.webm" oncanplay="loaderVideo();"></video>
```

```js
$(document).on("ready", function() {
            function loaderVideo() {
                $('.big-icon').fadeIn(1000);
                $('.loader').fadeOut(500);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es una cuestión de *ámbito* de las funciones. Para que tu código funcione debes declarar `loaderVideo` fuera del *ámbito* de document.ready y llamarla desde dentro. Esto hará que la función sea llamada después de la carga del DOM.

Eso no impedirá que puedas acceder a los elementos del DOM desde `loaderVideo`, como se puede ver en el código de prueba.

Por cierto, la recomendación es usar `function` en vez de `document.ready`, declarado obsoleto desde jQuery 3.

```js
$(function() {
  loaderVideo();
});

function loaderVideo() {
  /*Prueba de que se puede acceder a los elementos del DOM*/
  var testVal=$('#test').val();
  alert("Me has llamado :-) El input en el DOM tiene el valor: "+testVal);
  //$('.big-icon').fadeIn(1000);
  //$('.loader').fadeOut(500);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" value="input test" />
```

---

Para poder usarla dentro de document.ready tendrías que hacer algo como esto (menos elegante).

```js
$(function() {

  window.loaderVideo = function loaderVideo(msg) {
    alert(msg);
  }
  loaderVideo("Me has llamado :-(");
  alert("Más código");
  loaderVideo("Me llamaste de nuevo");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```